# UICollectionView auto scroll to cell at IndexPath

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Before loading the collection view user sets the number of image in the array of collection view. All of the cells don't fit on the screen. I have 30 cells and only 6 on the screen.

The question: How to scroll to the cell with desired image automatically at the load of UICollectionView?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I've found that scrolling in `viewWillAppear` may not work reliably because the collection view hasn't finished it's layout yet; you may scroll to the wrong item.

I've also found that scrolling in `viewDidAppear` will cause a momentary flash of the unscrolled view to be visible.

And, if you scroll every time through `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, the user won't be able to manually scroll because some collection layouts cause subview layout every time you scroll.

Here's what I found works reliably:

Objective C :

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // If we haven't done the initial scroll, do it once.
    if (!self.initialScrollDone) {
        self.initialScrollDone = YES;
    
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:self.myInitialIndexPath
                                    atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Swift :

```
 override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

      if !self.initialScrollDone {

         self.initialScrollDone = true
         self.testNameCollectionView.scrollToItem(at:selectedIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice tip. I'll emphasize using an `initialScrollDone` flag as LenK has done since this method will get called more than once and if you call scrollToItemAtIndexPath: more than once it seems to render the collectionView unscrollable(iOS simulator iPhone 5/iOS 8)

Comment: Works great in iOS8. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me in iOS 8.3. Had to call `[self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];` before, which also works when you do this within `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: This definitely should be the accepted answer. The answer above gave me a flash as the first cell was shown and then updated with my new cell, this method transitions seamlessly.

Comment: this also works on iOS 9, and also does not mess up my auto layout.

Comment: This caused a crash: attempted to scroll to invalid index path. I tried to access the first element. I'm on iOS 9.

Comment: Nevermind, the crash was occurring because I was using indexPathWithIndex method to initialize an indexPath.

Comment: Worked for me on iOS 9!! Thanks!

Comment: Works on iOS 10.  Amazing that something so simple should be so tricky.

Answer (score 186):

**New, Edited Answer:**

Add this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

**SWIFT**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 12, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: [.centeredVertically, .centeredHorizontally], animated: true)
}
```

Normally, `.centerVertically` is the case

**ObjC**

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
   [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:12 inSection:0];
   [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically | UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
}
```

**Old answer working for older iOS**

Add this in `viewWillAppear`:

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:NO];
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to use. I have the number of the object in the array and I know the name of that object. But don't know how to put correct indexPath... Any ideas?

Comment: You can easily create `indexPath`: `[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:numberOfTheObject inSection:sectionNumber]`

Comment: Had some errors. But then I've put all the mentioned code inside (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{} and now it's working fine. Thanx Bogdan.

Comment: How can I 'zoom' into the cell, and show it magnified?

Comment: This doesn't work reliably on iOS 7.1 and can lead to the collection view appearing as a black screen. I also didn't want to maintain state like the solution in viewDidLayoutSubviews below. What I did is simply performed a [self.view layoutIfNeeded] right before the call to scrollToItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Thanks @DanielGalasko, going to adjust the answer

Comment: `viewWillAppear` it doesn't work. add it on `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: writing these lines in some other method. It's not working

Comment: those who have horizontal collectionview should use UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally

Comment: sir how to put the indexpath in paramter in collectionView.scrollToItem

Answer (score 17):

I totally agree with the above answer. The only thing is that for me the solution was set the code in viewDidAppear

```
viewDidAppear 
{
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:YES];
}
```

When I used the viewWillAppear the scrolling didn't work.

Comment: viewDidAppear has the disadvantage that you see the collection view moving/flashing, the view has already appeared (as the name implies) ... I really wonder why Apple has not designed this not so unusual case in a nicer way, the viewDidLayoutSubviews way is a bit awkward

Answer (score 13):

**Swift:**

```
your_CollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

**Swift 3**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: itemIndex, section: sectionIndex)

collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.right, animated: true)
```

**Scroll Position:**

```
UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally / UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredVertically
```

Answer (score 12):

this seemed to work for me, its similar to another answer but has some distinct differences:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{     
   [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
   NSArray *visibleItems = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
   NSIndexPath *currentItem = [visibleItems objectAtIndex:0];
   NSIndexPath *nextItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:someInt inSection:currentItem.section];

   [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextItem atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use GCD to dispatch the scroll into the next iteration of main run loop in viewDidLoad to achieve this behavior. The scroll will be performed before the collection view is showed on screen, so there will be no flashing.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^{
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = YOUR_DESIRED_INDEXPATH;
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
    });
}
```

Comment: how to get indexpath when position is 3?

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to mentioned above.
Call after data load:

**Swift**

```
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .right)
```

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend doing it in `collectionView: willDisplay:` Then you can be sure that the collection view delegate delivers something. 
Here my example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    /// this is done to set the index on start to 1 to have at index 0 the last image to have a infinity loop
    if !didScrollToSecondIndex {
        self.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0), at: .left, animated: false)
        didScrollToSecondIndex = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that using didEndDisplaying, instead of willDisplay was the way to get this to work properly. willDisplay was okay as long as the cell was on the screen; however, if the cell wasn't on the screen yet, this method did not scroll me to it. didEndDisplaying though worked perfectly for that use case. Appreciate your answer setting me on the right path!

Answer (score 2):

All answers here - hacks. I've found better way to scroll collection view somewhere after relaodData:
Subclass collection view layout what ever layout you use, override method prepareLayout, after super call set what ever offset you need.
ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34192787/1400119

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collctionView: UICollectionView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl! {
        didSet {
                  pageControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.pageControl(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
              }
    }
    let list = [ #colorLiteral(red: 0.5843137255, green: 0.8823529412, blue: 0.8274509804, alpha: 1) , #colorLiteral(red: 0.9882352941, green: 0.8901960784, blue: 0.5411764706, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.5843137255, green: 0.8823529412, blue: 0.8274509804, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411765, green: 0.5058823529, blue: 0.5058823529, alpha: 1),  #colorLiteral(red: 0.5843137255, green: 0.8823529412, blue: 0.8274509804, alpha: 1) , #colorLiteral(red: 0.9882352941, green: 0.8901960784, blue: 0.5411764706, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.5843137255, green: 0.8823529412, blue: 0.8274509804, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411765, green: 0.5058823529, blue: 0.5058823529, alpha: 1),  #colorLiteral(red: 0.5843137255, green: 0.8823529412, blue: 0.8274509804, alpha: 1) , #colorLiteral(red: 0.9882352941, green: 0.8901960784, blue: 0.5411764706, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.5843137255, green: 0.8823529412, blue: 0.8274509804, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411765, green: 0.5058823529, blue: 0.5058823529, alpha: 1)]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        pageControl?.numberOfPages = 11
        
        let flowlayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowlayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: collctionView.frame.size.width, height: collctionView.frame.size.height)
        flowlayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        flowlayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        flowlayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        collctionView.collectionViewLayout = flowlayout
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func pageControl(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / Int(scrollView.frame.width)
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.view.backgroundColor = list[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collctionView.frame.size.width, height: collctionView.frame.size.height)
    }
    
   
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.