# Rendering dynamic HTML Code in UITextView in CollectionView making issues

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

We are developing a messaging application and are using a collectionview that contains several types of cells. The cells have different types with dynamic sizes, one of the cells should show styled text with multicolors and formats received from webserver.
The cell shows this correctly on first view but after scroll the app crash on HTML re-rendering with error:

> Received unhandled ObjectiveC exception: NSRangeException

We implemented our collectionview based on this link
[UICollectionView insert cells above maintaining position (like Messages.app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548257/uicollectionview-insert-cells-above-maintaining-position-like-messages-app)

Below is the code:

We tried to add the `NSAttribute`s calculated to cache but we are not able to retrieve them back as `NSAttribute`s since they are saved as strings.

**ChatCollectionViewSource.cs**

```cs
[Export("collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:"), CompilerGenerated]
public virtual CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var msg = chatMessages[indexPath.Row];
    var estimatedFrame = new CGRect(0, 0, 220, 1000);

    if(msg.Message.IsHtml()){
        var ss = NSString ss = new NSString(msg.Message);
        var htmlAttributes = TextHelper.GetHtmlNSAttributes(ss);
        var estimatedFrame = TextHelper.GetEstimatedCGRectHtml(htmlAttributes); 
        return new CGSize(this.view.Frame.Width, estimatedFrame.Height + 24);
    }
    else {
        // return cgsize of nonhtml text cell
    }
}

public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var msg = chatMessages[indexPath.Row];
    var textCell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("message_cell_identifier", indexPath) as MessageCell;

    textCell.Layer.ShouldRasterize = true;
    textCell.Layer.RasterizationScale = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;

    var estimatedFrame = new CGRect(0, 0, 220, 1000);

    if (msg.Message.IsHTML()) // html
    {
        NSString ss = new NSString(msg.Message);

        NSAttributedString NSAttributes = null;
        NSAttributes = TextHelper.GetHtmlNSAttributes(ss);

        textCell.SetHTML(NSAttributes, msg.Date, msg.Id.ToString());
        textCell.NSAttributedString = NSAttributes;
    }
    else
    {
        textCell.SetText(msg, msg.Date);
        estimatedFrame = TextHelper.GetEstimatedCGRect(msg.Message); // get estimated frame
    }

    textCell.SetFrame(estimatedFrame, chatMessages[indexPath.Row].IsSend, this.view, msg);

    return textCell;
}
```

**MessageCell.cs**

```cs
public void SetHTML(NSAttributedString NSAttributes, DateTime dateTime, string Id = null)
{
    //ChatTextView.TextStorage.BeginEditing();
    try
    {
        ChatTextView.TextColor = null;

        if (NSAttributes != null)
        {
            DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
            {
                ChatTextView.AttributedText = new NSMutableAttributedString(NSAttributes);
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exception);
    }}
```

TextHelper.cs

```cs
    public static NSAttributedString GetHtmlNSAttributes(NSString HTMLtext)
        {
            var HTMLStyle = "<style>.body{font-family: '-apple-system', 'GothamMedium'; font-size:13; color:rgb(179, 178, 178);}</style>";
            var text = HTMLStyle + "<div class='body'>" + HTMLtext + "</div>";
            var ns = (NSString)text;

            var myHtmlData = ns.Encode(NSStringEncoding.Unicode);

            var options = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes
            {
                DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML
            };

            NSError error = new NSError();
            error = null;
            NSDictionary dict = new NSDictionary();
            dict = null;

            try
            {
                var attrString = new NSAttributedString(myHtmlData, options, out dict, ref error);

                return attrString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myHtmlData);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(options);
                return null;
                //throw ex;
            }
        }
```

This actually works perfectly

We are trying to add feature:
Get last 50 messages (Infinite Scroll)
When the user scrolls to top of the list

**ChatViewController.cs**

```cs
#region scrolled to top observer
scrolledToTopObs = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver((NSString)"scrolled_to_top",
async (notification) =>
{
    var moreMessages = await Static.DB.getChatsAsync(this.CaseId, this.UserType, ++page);

    if (moreMessages.Count == 0)
        return;

    list.InsertRange(0, moreMessages);

    Debug.WriteLine("items count in list: " + list.Count);

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548257/uicollectionview-insert-cells-above-maintaining-position-like-messages-app

    NSIndexPath[] insertedPaths = new NSIndexPath[moreMessages.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < insertedPaths.Length; i++)
        insertedPaths[i] = NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(i, 0);

    DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
    {

        var bottomOffset = ChatCollectionView.ContentSize.Height - ChatCollectionView.ContentOffset.Y;
        CATransaction.Begin();
        CATransaction.DisableActions = true;
        ChatCollectionView.PerformBatchUpdates(() =>
        {
            ChatCollectionView.InsertItems(insertedPaths);
        },
        (finished) =>
        {
            ChatCollectionView.SetContentOffset(new CGPoint(0, ChatCollectionView.ContentSize.Height - bottomOffset), false);
            CATransaction.Commit();
        });
    });
});
```

The app crashes after `DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync()` with this crash report:

> 2019-05-10 12:10:38.152 MyApp[1890:923892] Xamarin.iOS: Received
>   unhandled ObjectiveC exception: NSRangeException *** -[__NSArrayM
>   objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 16 beyond bounds [0 .. 15]
>   2019-05-10 12:10:38.156 MyApp[1890:923892].......................
>   HTMLString of type NSAttributedString is null 2019-05-10 12:10:38.163
>   MyApp[1890:923892] Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSRangeException Reason: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]:
>   index 16 beyond bounds [0 .. 15] Native stack trace:  0
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001bb829ebc  +
>   252   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001ba9f9a50
>   objc_exception_throw + 56     2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001bb7a1384 _CFArgv + 0    3   CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001bb724b78  + 0     4   UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82d4f5c  + 1836  5   UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82d69dc  + 260   6   UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82d0d48  + 44    7   UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82b3d50  + 1648  8   UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82b3580  + 92    9   Foundation
>   0x00000001bc2c9420 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 404   10  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001bb7ba718  + 28    11  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001bb7ba448  + 864   12  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001bb7b9c7c  + 248   13  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001bb7b4b58  + 1880  14  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001bb7b40e0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436     15  UIFoundation
>   0x00000001c5e42368  + 1728  16  UIFoundation
>   0x00000001c5e4533c  + 28    17  UIFoundation
>   0x00000001c5e923ec _NSReadAttributedStringFromURLOrData + 8120    18 
>   UIFoundation                        0x00000001c5e45278  +
>   136   19  MyApp                               0x000000010318b498 MyApp
>   + 5911704     20  MyApp                               0x0000000103143104 MyApp + 5615876  21  MyApp
>   0x000000010314329c MyApp + 5616284    22  MyApp
>   0x0000000102ca95f4 MyApp + 792052     23  MyApp
>   0x0000000102c7594c MyApp + 579916     24  MyApp
>   0x000000010305b598 MyApp + 4666776    25  Mono
>   0x0000000105a38f08 mono_get_runtime_build_info + 1332     26  Mono
>   0x0000000105add8a4 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 152  27  Mono
>   0x0000000105ae1214 mono_runtime_invoke + 160  28  MyApp
>   0x0000000102c40e98 MyApp + 364184     29  MyApp
>   0x0000000102c40af0 MyApp + 363248     30  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82d53ac  + 2940  31  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82d69dc  + 260   32  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82d0830  + 224   33  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82c9054  + 228   34  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82ac2d4  + 10232     35  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82b3f90  + 92    36  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82b42c8  + 388   37  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82b4124  + 96    38  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82b40a8  + 84    39  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e82b3fe4  + 64    40  MyApp
>   0x00000001031868f8 MyApp + 5892344    41  MyApp
>   0x0000000103129e88 MyApp + 5512840    42  MyApp
>   0x0000000102cc1878 MyApp + 891000     43  MyApp
>   0x000000010315a830 MyApp + 5711920    44  MyApp
>   0x0000000103194a7c MyApp + 5950076    45  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00000001bb262484  + 16    46  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00000001bb20e9a4  + 1068  47  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001bb7b9ce4  + 12    48  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001bb7b4bac  + 1964  49  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001bb7b40e0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 2019-05-10 12:10:38.163
>   MyApp[1890:923892]    50  GraphicsServices
>   0x00000001bda2d584 GSEventRunModal + 100  51  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001e89c8c00 UIApplicationMain + 212    52  MyApp
>   0x00000001031914e4 MyApp + 5936356    53  MyApp
>   0x000000010312798c MyApp + 5503372    54  MyApp
>   0x000000010312794c MyApp + 5503308    55  MyApp
>   0x0000000102c591c0 MyApp + 463296     56  MyApp
>   0x000000010305b598 MyApp + 4666776    57  Mono
>   0x0000000105a38f08 mono_get_runtime_build_info + 1332     58  Mono
>   0x0000000105add8a4 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 152  59  Mono
>   0x0000000105ae3b54 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 120   60  Mono
>   0x0000000105a16bfc mono_jit_exec + 316    61  MyApp
>   0x000000010548777c _Z9__isctypeim + 56712     62  MyApp
>   0x0000000102c590b8 MyApp + 463032     63  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00000001bb272bb4  + 4
>
> 2019-05-10 12:10:38.163 MyApp[1890:923892]
>   Foundation.NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes reached top of
>   collectionview 12:10:38 PM items count in list: 300 objc[1890]:
>   Invalid or prematurely-freed autorelease pool 0x1057f33c8.
>
> **Native Crash Reporting**
>
> Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a
>   fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used
>   by your application.
>
> **Basic Fault Adddress Reporting**
>
> Memory around native instruction pointer...
>
> **Native stacktrace:**
>
> 0x105a30fc8 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/20685366-DEC9-4CB0-BA4E-3B41F073FEBD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono
>   : mono_dump_native_crash_info     0x105a270c8 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/20685366-DEC9-4CB0-BA4E-3B41F073FEBD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono
>   : mono_handle_native_crash    0x1bb4359f0 -
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib :      0x1bb3b780c -
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib :    0x1bb3b77a8 -
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib :    0x1ba9f94c4 -
>   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib :      0x1ba9f941c -
>   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

Comment: Index out of range, I would suggest you not testing with 50 messages, instead you can test with 5, 10 messages to find out the problem. And check the data if there is a null value.  And check the if the insertedPaths is right.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT the issue appear when HTML cell is found in the list if the list doest contain this (HTML Cell) will scroll normally without any issues.

Comment: Are you getting null NSAttributedString in `NSAttributes = TextHelper.GetHtmlNSAttributes(ss);` ?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes we are getting null for the NSAttributes

Comment: So you should avoid these null strings in method `GetHtmlNSAttributes`.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT the calculated NSAttributes are returning null but the value of SS is not null ..  i Updated the questuion and add the method GetHtmlNSAttributes code

Comment: I can't find out the real causes without debugging codes. You should add breakpoint in the HTML cell and find out the problem. Pay more attention to  Arrays as the exception is NSRangeException.