# Snap to cell in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I am currently using a CollectionView within my UIViewController that scrolls horizontally through a variable number of cells (There are 3 cells visible on the display at a time). I want it so that when the user finishes scrolling that the view smoothly snaps/pulls to the cell closest to the center of the screen. Does anyone have suggestions on how this could be done?

Comment: Hi, please take a look at this question, looks similar to what you want to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855945/uicollectionview-snap-onto-cell-when-scrolling-horizontally

Comment: P.S. Accepted answer is really great, I used the same approach

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for you fast reply! I did see that question but I was unable to get the accepted answer working. I am rather new to swift and I couldn't figure out how to implement Mark Bourke's solution. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What were you having trouble implementing in his solution?

Comment: Honestly I wasn't sure where to start in using it on a specific UICollectionView. I created a file to store the SnappingCollectionViewLayout subclass, but I wasn't sure in what context I was supposed to use the class within my UIViewController that contained the UICollectionView. I am sure it is a simple solution, my mind is just coming up blank.

Comment: After you create class SnappingCollectionViewLayout,
If you use storyboard or xib for your view controller, then just set the class name for your collection view layout in the Utilities(usually on the right side) tab from XCode.  http://joxi.net/p273pqs0YMNX27.jpg

Comment: I knew I was overlooking something simple! Wonderful. I will report back once I have had the chance to implment it. Thank you both!

Comment: Thank you for that screenshot, that did the trick.