# How to make a "selection ring" for uicollectionview?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

My goal is to create a ring that is in the middle of the collection view. When a cell stops in the ring I want to run a function and fetch the index path of that cell. I don't want true pagination but more snap scrolling.

To visualize what I want...
(This is an app on the app store)

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPfi0.jpg)

Notice that the black circle/ring stays in the same place while the collection view cells move.

[photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ILQf.jpg)

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: what you had tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried to add an image view as a subview to the collection view at the position of the first cell. For some reason the image view did not show up. I also need help figuring out how to have the uicollection view scroll in a way that it stops in the ring.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `UIImageView` above the `UICollectionView` and set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false`.

But if the ring overlay just contains a black and white circle (as it seems on the photo's), you don't need an `UIImageView`. Instead, you can compose this with two transparent `UIView`s on top op each other, of which you set `layer.borderColor` and `layer.borderWidth`.

Of course you also need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` on these two ring `UIView`s.

Then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33855945/1971013) you can find a few ideas of how to implement the snap scrolling.