# Scroll to cell but no select

Tags: swift

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIBarButtonItem` "Edit".When I tap "Edit" I push another controller with some data.I have 2 `UICollectionView` inside my controller and they scroll to cells with a specific `NSIndexPath`.For example in this image:
[image]

It works if I can see cells (from 1.0/5.0 to 2.5/5.0) but if the item of my IndexPath is 6 for example, my collectionView scrolls to the 6th cell (4.0/5.0) but it doesn't select it, and I got this result(as you can see cell's background is not black, so it is not selected):

[image]

This is my code:

```
var index = NSIndexPath(item: indexPathSelected.item, section: 0)
ratingCollectionView.collectionView.selectItem(at: index as IndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
ratingCollectionView.collectionView(collectionView, didSelectItemAt: index as IndexPath)
```

Comment: you need to show code! simply based on the description you can do **a lot** of things wrong.

Comment: Did you try `self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem:indexPathSelected.item, inSection:0), atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView auto scroll to cell at IndexPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985574/uicollectionview-auto-scroll-to-cell-at-indexpath)

Comment: Thank you, I missed view.layoutIfNeeded() in viewWillAppear.Now it works!