# How do I start a function after the Collection View is fully loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

How do I start a function after the Collection View is fully loaded?

I use override `func layoutSubviews()` but It's not working the way I want it to.

Thanks.

Comment: means you would like to call function after collectionview is filled with all data ?

Comment: Explain your problem in detail.

Comment: explain what is your goal?

Comment: Is there any networking involved? Or just want to detect, when collection view is loaded after a `reloadData()`?

Comment: There is not callback or completion block on reloadData for Collection View, furthermore reloadData call is not synchronous ( according to my empirical observations ). Please explain Your goal more clearly.

Comment: You have asked the [exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458586/how-can-i-start-function-when-uicollectionview-is-finished-loading) before. Please do not do this.

Comment: Please improve your original question, since it is still open, rather than asking a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Do as follow (obj - c)

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
       willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell 
    forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[collectionView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){
        //end of loading, now your collection view is fully loaded.
        // Now call the method you wanted to call
    }
}
```