# How do I set the collectionView position?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios13, swift5

I have a `UICollectionView` build like in the picture. For example, I choose the 5th button and closed and opened the application. I want the 5th button to appear on the screen when the application is opened again. In other words, the `UICollectionView` should not return to the first position when the application is opened again.

***https://i.hizliresim.com/mxX5qT.png***

Comment: can you post the image here, instead of giving links? what do you mean by closed and opened the application.?

Comment: Please show us some code of what you've tried.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15986085/4757272 use `scrollToIndex(at: IndexPath)` or something like that

Comment: You need to save the selected index like 5th and scroll to that cell when you return back to collection view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this at your collection view's `didSelectItem` func :

```swift
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
```

Hope it helps...